# Reactjs - Demo Application is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying setup react new setup but it is give me below error

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Cannot find module '@csstools/normalize.css'
```

can anyone suggest me to move forward

thanks in advance

Comment: create your own css file and import your external ccs there and included you created css in component.

Comment: check " /webpack.config.js" :-sample ref: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1086

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6886
check this link

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm able to solve the problem. The problem is that `package-lock.json` is pointing to the older packages. 
To fix, uninstall an install the package again

Uninstall package

```
$ sudo npm remove csstools/normalize.css
```

After that, we have to install again

```
$ npm install csstools/normalize.css
```

(removing sudo from the npm install command)

Comment: don't use sudo to install packages

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

now try again to run your scripts, it should work

https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox-example/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

I solve the same problem. The problem is that package-lock.json is pointing to the older packages. Not sure which package is but needs to be updated. The gist is that, you create a fresh reactapp, use your "package.json" to recreate "package-lock.json", and move it over back to your project. Do it *AFTER* you update the npm and clear the cache. Unfortunately, I didn't keep the exact sequence as I was trying to solve, following steps should be pretty close to what I did.

```
$ sudo npm cache clear --force
$ sudo npm install -g npm
$ cd <MYREACTAPPDIR>
$ npm install react@latest --save
$ cd ..
$ npx create-react-app tempapp
$ cp <MYREACTAPPDIR>/package.json tempapp/package.json
$ cd tempapp
$ npm install
$ cp package-lock.json ../<MYREACTAPPDIR>
$ cd ../<MYREACTAPPDIR>
$ rm -fr node_modules
$ npm install
$ npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (unfortunately a really annoying solution since it gets wiped whenever node_modules gets reinstalled), when recreating with `npx create-react-app` did not work.

1. Go to react-app/node_modules/@csstools
2. Change the name of the normalize.css folder into something else (ex. anormalize.css)
3. Take the files from the folder and paste them into the @csstools folder
4. Delete the anormalize.css folder

[Source](https://forum.codewithmosh.com/d/695-3-your-first-react-app-can-t-start-run-react-app-because-of-error)

Answer (score 0):

fixed issue by updating npm to latest version.

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting this error, chances are that you haven't used `npx` to create the react app. You must have used -

```
create-react-app project_name
```

Delete the project folder and reinstall it using -

```
npx create-react-app project_name
```

It should work this time. `npx` is a tool for node packages, which also installs some third party packages that running `create-react-app` alone might not install, hence throws the error.